# How to determine the formula for the nth term of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I discovered a kind of sequence, but which I don't know how to determine the general formula for the nth term. How it's possible to do so?

$$a_1 = 1 \\ a_n = a_{n-1} + 2^{\log_2(2^n-2)-n}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  It would be better to type your posts, rather than linking to images.  Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  if you don't know how to format the math.

Answer (score 2):

$$2^{\log_2(2^n-2)-n} = 2^{\log_2(2^n-2)}\cdot2^{-n} = (2^n-2)2^{-n} = 1-2^{-n+1}$$

so $a_n = n - \sum_{i=2}^{n} 2^{-i+1}$ and this sum is a geometric one.